# Create string of range of grid selected cells

Tags: c#, grid

I have a grid with check boxes in each cell and user can check any cell.
Grid has columns and rows captions as shown in image.

I want to create a string which shows range of selected cells
required string pattern is shown in image.

Is there any library that can help?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmEtG.png)

Comment: Which Application Type are your using? WinForms, WPF, ...

Comment: @VolkmarRigo: _Winforms

Comment: Simple things doesn't need library (and asking for one is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Have you tried anything yet? The task is rather interesting, expressing selected areas in a form of collection of excel-like ranges is probably existing mathematical/algorithmical problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The goal of this site is to help people having issues with problems which they have shown some effort and have shown some amount of work done in the problem. Please restructure this question or post a new one stating what you have actually done.